# Мог ли я что-то упустить в выделении и освобождении неуправляемой памяти?

Tags: c#, инспекция-кода

Я описал класс, который работает как синглтон и в то же время при выделении памяти через него, он сохраняет указатели на выделенные блоки до тех пор, пока не будет вызван метод ручной очистки памяти, т.е. `Free`, или же не подойдет к концу время жизни объекта *(завершение программы)*.

Можно ли в нем что-либо улучшить, и не упустил ли я чего из виду?

Предполагается потокобезопасность, а класс необходим для построения связей между demuxer'ами, и кодеками

```
[DebuggerDisplay("Not freed memory allocations: {_allocatedMemory.Count}")]
public sealed unsafe class Memory : IDisposable
{
    public static readonly Memory Instance;

    [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.RootHidden)]
    private readonly LinkedList<IntPtr> _allocatedMemory;

    static Memory()
    {
        Instance = new Memory();
    }

    private Memory()
    {
        _allocatedMemory = new LinkedList<IntPtr>();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        ReleaseUnmanagedResources();
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    public T* Alloc<T>() where T : unmanaged
    {
        return (T*) Alloc((uint) sizeof(T));
    }

    public void* Alloc(uint size)
    {
        IntPtr allocPtr = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem((int) size);
        return allocPtr == IntPtr.Zero
            ? allocPtr.ToPointer()
            : _allocatedMemory.AddLast(allocPtr).Value.ToPointer();
    }

    public IntPtr Alloc(int size)
    {
        return (IntPtr) Alloc((uint) size);
    }

    public bool Free<T>(T** ptr) where T : unmanaged
    {
        return Free((void**) ptr);
    }

    public bool Free(void** ptr)
    {
        if (*ptr == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        IntPtr intPtr = new IntPtr(*ptr);
        bool result = Free(ref intPtr);

        if (result)
        {
            *ptr = null;
        }

        return result;
    }

    public bool Free(ref IntPtr pointer)
    {
        if (pointer == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            return false;
        }

        LinkedListNode<IntPtr> node = _allocatedMemory.Find(pointer);

        if (node == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        IntPtr tmpPtr = node.Value;
        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(tmpPtr);
        _allocatedMemory.Remove(node);

        return true;
    }

    private void ReleaseUnmanagedResources()
    {
        foreach (IntPtr intPtr in _allocatedMemory)
        {
            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(intPtr);
        }
    }

    ~Memory()
    {
        ReleaseUnmanagedResources();
    }
}
```

Comment: Как много неуправляемой памяти выделяется? Возможно, есть смысл подумать об использовании [GC.AddMemoryPressure](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.gc.addmemorypressure?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: `Предполагается потокобезопасность` LinkedList же вроде не потокобезопасный

Comment: @tym32167, Потокобезопасность реализовано в другом месте, блокируется сам объект `Instance`.